# Base64 (GNU/Linux vs Python)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-2.7

On Linux I can use the command "base64" to encode a string or "python -m base64 -e". They had the same output, but inside of the Python shell, when I use the base64, I had a different output.

```
#Linux prompt

Command : echo 'HelloWorld' | base64

Output  : SGVsbG9Xb3JsZAo=

Command : echo 'HelloWorld' | python -m base64 -e

Output  : SGVsbG9Xb3JsZAo=
```

--== inside of the Python shell ==--

```
import base64

word = "HelloWorld".encode()
new_word = base64.b64encode(word)
print(word)
print(new_word)
```

Output:

```
b'HelloWord'
b'SGVsbG9Xb3JsZA=='
```

What can I do? And why this is happening?

#### Solved:

Why that happens:

Because the echo puts " \n " at the end of the string.

Comment: Umm, `word = "DaviMello".encode()`? Shouldn't that be `HelloWorld`?

Comment: echo added `\n`

Comment: The command you are talking about is not part of Linux. Linux is the kernel only, therefore the most common combination of kernel and tools used by most distributions is called GNU/Linux. `base64` is from the GNU part. [details](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/ia64/ch01s02.html.en)

Comment: Thanks all, @Aran-Fey yes, i miss the example i will fix ;

Comment: @KlausD. thanks, i will do right on next time. :)

Comment: @Dan , ths that is the problem. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot that `echo` outputs a newline.

```
$ echo -n 'HelloWorld' | base64
SGVsbG9Xb3JsZA==
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Solved my problem.

Comment: the -n is what was needed. thank you!